# Non Width Special Character Removal

Tags: javascript, html, non-ascii-characters

Below is my HTML Code to get the input from User.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD=POST onSubmit="javascript:return(exa(this.form.model.value))">

<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=MODEL VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME=SUBMIT VALUE="Next">

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When User entered the Model name (Having zero width special characters) --> ​​PMUE4526AAAAAA

Below is the java script to remove the non-ascii characters. but, it's not working for me.

```
function exa(myString)
{
  alert("String: "+myString);alert("String_length: "+myString.length);
  myString=  myString.replace(/[^\x20-\x7e]/g,'');
  alert("String: "+myString);alert("String_length: "+myString.length);
```

Whenever i am trying to display the value which i received from HTML, `"&#8203;&#8203;PMUE4526AAAAAA"` it's showing like that. so, my Java script program considers `"&#8203;"` (7 characters), not a special character.

Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: It looks like your user is entering HTML, not the actual characters.

Comment: @Bergi, User is entering through HTML. I just wanted to remove those non-width characters to process further. Please help me to remove the special characters feeded from HTML source.

Comment: `.value` does not read the HTML source, but the property of the DOM - the actual user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex in the replace: /([^\x00-\x7F]|&#[0-9]+;)/g

Comment: That's a rabbit hole. For example, there's also `&#x200b;` for that same character.

Comment: @kj_ now, the special characters got removed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @msiva1989 I suspect you'll have the same issue tomorrow. It'll be "&#x200b;&#x200b;PMUE4526AAAAAA" instead.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks for the information. Want to remove all invisible characters.

Comment: @Ouroborus Hex Code: &#x200b and Decimal Code: &#8203 is same for this non-visible character.

Comment: @msiva1989 Yup. So now you have something else to look for.